# How to iterate over files using awk, bash, or ruby?

Tags: bash, awk, ruby

I have three markdown files on my machine:

```
$ ls | grep md
bar.md
baz.md
foo.md
```

Each file has the given content:

```
$ cat *md
i am bar
i am baz
i am foo
```

As an example, I'd like "loop over all the files matching the `*.md` pattern and print the pattern: `file_name: file_contents`".

I'm most comfortable working with ruby. But I'd like to practice my [bash for-loops](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) and also develop my [awk](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html) skills.

Ruby is the easiest for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# iterate over all markdown files in current directory

Dir.glob('*.md').each do |some_file|
  puts "#{some_file}: #{File.read(some_file)}"
end
```

output:

```
$ ./iterate_over_files.rb
bar.md: i am bar
baz.md: i am baz
foo.md: i am foo
```

And from following the linked [bash resource](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) I created the following for-loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# iterate over all markdown files in current directory

for some_file in *.md
do
  echo $some_file: `cat $some_file`
done
```

which gives the same output:

```
$ diff <(./iterate_over_files.sh) <(./iterate_over_files.rb) # no difference
```

I know from watching a presentation by [Brian Kernaghan](https://youtu.be/Sg4U4r_AgJU?t=22m49s) and from reviewing [his slides](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yurusd7wxjofrb5/Computer%20Science%20video%20slides%20for%20Brian%20Kernighan%20YouTube%20video.pdf?dl=0) that this is a great chance to use awk because it follows the pattern:

```
for each file
  for each input line 
    for each pattern
      if the pattern matches input line
        do the action
```

- How do I leverage this pattern using awk and iterate over all the markdown files and print a formatted result?

Comment: Your code ``echo $some_file: `cat $some_file` `` would be better written `echo "$some_file:" $(cat "$some_file")`. The `$(...)` is a modern replacement for `` `...` ``, and you should always double-quote variables (or interpolated variables) unless you know you have a specific exception. (Strangely, this is one of them, where the `$(...)` should probably not be included in the quoted string.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `bash` manual, you should use `$(< FILE)` rather than `$(cat FILE)`. But there is no need to use command substitution at all:

```
for some_file in *.md
do
  echo -n "$some_file: "
  cat $some_file
done
```

Since you are already aware of process substitution, you could also do something like:

```
for some_file in *.md
do
  cat <(echo -n "$some_file: ") $some_file
done
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this, processes each file and outputs the filename by using the FILENAME variable.

```
$ awk '{print FILENAME":",$0}' *.md
bar.md: i am bar
baz.md: i am baz
foo.md: i am foo
$
```

Or this one, little harder on the eyes, but just sets $0 to the filename followed by the file contents.  Default action for `awk` is to print $0, so that's why it doesn't need a `print`.

```
$ awk '$0=FILENAME": "$0' *.md
bar.md: i am bar
baz.md: i am baz
foo.md: i am foo
$
```

Another approach.  Instead of using FILENAME, uses the ARGV array of arguments.

```
$ awk '$0=ARGV[++z]": "$0' *.md
bar.md: i am bar
baz.md: i am baz
foo.md: i am foo
$
```

Comment: The first example makes sense: you're using the `FILENAME` builtin and printing the entire record with `$0`. But can you add an explanation for the second example? It seems like you're changing the value of `$0` yet it's continuing to print two different results.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I'm still confused on the order. Based on your code I'd expect the first row to be `bar.md: bar.md`

Comment: If the files have several lines in them, and you only want the first line prepended with the filename, you could use BEGINFILE like this:

    awk 'BEGINFILE { printf "%s: ", FILENAME } { print }'